# Choosing where a line breaks with CSS

Tags: css

I've got a menu written with a `ul` and `li`s, and I'm having trouble getting the lines to wrap in the right place. Here's the HTML:

```
<li><span>●</span>&nbsp;<a href="/spl">Scottish Premier League</a></li>
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
● Scottish
Premier League
```

But it looks like this:

```
●
Scottish Premier
League
```

The `span` with the dot is targetted with jQuery to expand the league to show the clubs, and the `a` navigates to the league page.

I've tried using `white-space: nowrap;` on the `li`, but that widens the `ul` and messes up the rest of the layout. I've tried putting `<wbr>` tabs in the league name, but that has no effect. Anything else I can try?

Comment: can you show us your css for the ul and li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. The problem was a `display: inline-block` on the `<a>` tag.